# how to show html elements from python cgi file into ajax file

Tags: python, html, ajax

Please I want to handle the front-end in python as much as possible and make it dynamic by ajax:

this is the client side:

```
  <div id="gene">
<!-- <select id="gene"> -->
<!-- add an empty value -->
<!--<option value="*">-- Select --</option> -->
<!--</select>-->
</div>
```

And the Ajax function in the same file:

```
 var updateGeneInput = function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'get.py',
                    type: 'get',
                    data: {'table':'gene'},
                    success: function(data){

                   $("#gene").html(data);
                   }
                });
            };
```

And I want to retrieve the options to populate the drop list using the cgi (get.py):

```
 if (table == "gene"):
            query = """
            SELECT category
            FROM Categories
            """
            cursor.execute(query)
            rows=cursor.fetchall()
            print("""<select >""")

            print("""<option value='*'>- Select -</option>""")

            for row in rows:
               print("""<option value="s%">s%</option>"""%row)

            print("""</select>""")
```

It does show the results but not in drop list.
[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: does `data` has something in it or not ?

Comment: this Ajax so far shows retrieve and show the results from the query on the page, but as line not as drop list. I want to show a drop list. I hope I answered your question! Thank you.

Comment: As a `line` ?  .Can you add your response which you get in ajax call in your question as well  ?

Comment: I added image for that. As you can see I get the options in line but I want them in drop list!

Comment: data are returning as string not as option  ..Sorry i don't know python .. but , try to `json` to load option in ajax . here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758066/populate-second-dropdown-based-on-the-value-selected-in-the-first-dropdown-in-fl)